# Authorize NET exception Line item 1 is invalid

Tags: authorize.net

Can someone help to set up multiple line items for transaction in Authorize NET

here is code example

```cs
 var lineItem = new LineItemType();
                    lineItem.itemId = "test";
                    lineItem.name = paymentDetail.Name;
                    lineItem.description = paymentDetail.StartDate.ToShortDateString();
                    lineItem.quantity = paymentDetail.Quantity;
                    lineItem.unitPrice = paymentDetail.UnitPrice;
                    lineItem.taxable = false;
```

I am getting error:

Response Sub Code: 1

Response Reason Code: 270

Response Reason Details: Line item 1 is invalid.

Comment: My solution was not to use decimals for lineItem.quantity.
For example the field **quantity** in **LineItemType** is decimal but if you use 
`lineItem.quantity =0.5668;` 
it will throw error Line item 1 is invalid
if you round the quantity to 1 it will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5):

Line Item quanitity can only be up to two decimal places. So if you change your quanitity from `0.5668` to `0.57` it will also work. (See page 24 of the [AIM guide](http://www.authorize.net/support/AIM_guide.pdf))